# excel shared formula expansion

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, worksheet-function

I am using the OpenXML libraries from C# to read Excel files.

One of my requirements is to be able to show the exact formula for each cell that has one. The OpenXML encoded file uses "shared formulas" to reduce file size.

Like this:

```
D3 : <x:f t="shared" ref="D3:D6" si="1" >D2+C3</x:f><x:v >130</x:v>
D4 : <x:f t="shared" si="1"  /><x:v >136</x:v>
D5 : <x:f t="shared" si="1"  /><x:v >141</x:v>
D6 : <x:f t="shared" si="1"  /><x:v >147</x:v>
```

Its a fairly simple root formula in the example above (D2+C3) and obviously these can be arbitrarily complex.

What I want to know is if there is a library or example code available that takes any lower cell (e.g. D4,D5,D6) and return the "unshared" formula?

e.g. for D6 this would return "D5+C6"

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that Excel is installed? I imagine this might be easier if you can use COM interop to simply load the spreadsheet and then access that cell.

Comment: alas no, Excel itself is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily, but it can be done. What I would do is use Linq.

First I would find any cells where `<v:f>.Value <> ""` and `<v:f>.@t = "shared"`. Then I would do a `.TakeWhile` of the `.ElementsAfterSelf` where `<v:f>.Value = ""` and `<v:f>.@t = "shared"`.

Once I have that IEnumerable(Of XElement), I would then use a parser for the formula on the first one<sup>1</sup> and then do a `For Each` to create a new formula for each XElement, incrementing the cell's relative value(s).

<sup>1</sup><sub>The recent series by Eric White on [Writing a Recursive Descent Parser using C# and LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/06/29/writing-a-recursive-descent-parser-using-c-and-linq.aspx) is probably the best I've seen.</sub>

Comment: I was afraid this was the case! Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @FreddySmith Few years later, still have the same problem of expanding shared cell formulas with Open XML. Can you share your solution ? Regards.